# SQL query/functions to flatten a multiple table item and hierarchical item links

Tags: sql-server, pivot, query-optimization, hierarchical-data, flatten

I have the data structure below, storing items and links between them in parent-child relashionship.
I need to display the result as show below, one line by parent, with all children.
Values are the ItemCodes by item type, for ex. C-1 and C-2 are the 2 first items of type C, and so on.

In a previous application version, there were only one C and one H maximum for each P.
So I did a max() and group by mix and the result was there.
But now, parents may be linked to different types and number of children.

I tried several techniques including adding temporary tables, views, use of PIVOT, ROLLUP, CUBE, stored procedures and cursors (!), but nothing worked for this specific problem.
I finally succeeded to adapt the query. However, there are many select from (select ...) clauses, as well as row_number based queries.
Also, the result is not dynamic, meaning the number of columns is fixed (which is acceptable).

My question is: what would be your approach for such issue (if possible in a single query)? Thank you!

The table structure:

```
 Item
-------------------------------
 ItemId  | ItemCode | ItemType
-------------------------------
 1       |   P1     |    P
 2       |   C11    |    C
 3       |   H11    |    H
 4       |   H12    |    H
 5       |   P2     |    P
 6       |   C21    |    C
 7       |   C22    |    C
 8       |   C23    |    C
 9       |   H21    |    H


 ItemLink
---------------------------------------
 LinkId  | ParentItemId | ChildItemId
---------------------------------------
 1       |      1       |      2
 2       |      1       |      3
 3       |      1       |      4
 4       |      2       |      6
 5       |      2       |      7
 6       |      2       |      8
 7       |      2       |      9


 Expcted Result
-----------------------------------------------------
 P    C-1    C-2   ...   C-N    H1    H2    ...   H-N
-----------------------------------------------------
 P1   C11    NULL  NULL  NULL   H11   H12   NULL  NULL
 P2   C21    C22   C23   NULL   H21   NULL  NULL  NULL
 ...
```

Part of my current query (which is working):
!http://s12.postimg.org/r64tgjjnh/SOQuestion.png

Comment: Pretty sure you need to do a DYNAMIC PIVOT, which there are many examples of, if you google that.

Comment: I already tried a pivot. But the issue is that I can't manage to get it working with a pivot, because the columns are "not unique", meaning if they were months we could have "May, May, May, June, June" for example.

Comment: Why would there be columns that are not unique?    That isn't shown in your sample data or expected results.

Comment: Sorry, the columns are not really "unique"; you would have "May1, May2, May3, June1, June2" if you prefer. We then may or may not have a value for each one of these columns. In each line of the expected result you can see the parent P which is always there and then the children which depending on the type and the ItemLink table may or may not be there for the corresponding parent.

Comment: In that case my earlier comment still stands.   please google "SQL DYNAMIC PIVOT EXAMPLES".   It will allow you to generate columns that you have no data for.

Comment: Googling what you suggested indeed returns results which may work for me (once I figure how they work exactly). I had found dynamic queries examples (more for dynamic column adding with XML STUFF function) and also pivot, but not the one you mentioned. Thanks for your help it is much appreciated!